# getIntent().getData() returns previous url in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to enable deep linking in my app . So my Intent- Filter looks like below

```
<intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="*.showonthecloud.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="*.showonthecloud.com"
                android:scheme="https" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />                
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALL_APPS" />
        </intent-filter>
```

When clicking the url from other app (Gmail App) my app got opened.But get the previously clicked url. The implemented code is

```
Intent deepLinkIntent = getIntent();

dataUri = deepLinkIntent.getData();
```

The printed value shows the previous one

```
Log.d(TAG, "Received url from intent :data uri==>" +dataUri);
```

I got one link http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/153521/android-intent-getdata-returns-the-same-value
From this can't get any answer.

Comment: Have you tried overriding `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` ?

Comment: I think it's possible your Activity is already running and the deep link is being delivered to it in `onNewIntent()`. If so, override that and call `setIntent()` inside of it to set the intent for the Activity.

Comment: @dymmeh  I have tried with onNewIntent(). But onNewIntent() not called.

Comment: @dymmeh now a days its working. Its use of onNewIntent() method.